# How to disable field in woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, woocommerce, filter-woocommerce

I am trying to disable my address 1 and address 2 fields on checkout page.
I have used the below working code on my-account page, I tried to use the code after editing on checkout page to disable the address 1 and address 2 field. But unfortunately it doesn't work, Kindly help.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readonly_billing_account_fields', 25, 1 );
function readonly_billing_account_fields ( $billing_fields ) {
    // Only my account billing address for logged in users
    if( is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page() ){

        $readonly = ['readonly' => 'readonly'];

        $billing_fields['address_1']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $billing_fields['address_2']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Comment: just remove completely your **`IF`** statement, so `if( is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page() ){`and the related closing bracket as the hook `woocommerce_checkout_fields` is only used on checkout pages, so no need of anything.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried that but it did not worked for me, anyways I got my answer :)

Comment: Sorry but this works… There is no need of an if statement as the hook `woocommerce_checkout_fields` is triggered only in checkout page. So the answer below is not correct. Now `$billing_fields['address_1']['custom_attributes']` need to be replaced with `$billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['custom_attributes']`

Comment: Now in your code  `$billing_fields['address_1']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;` need to be replaced with `$billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;`  and  `$billing_fields['address_2']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;` need to be replaced with `$billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;` … and it will work without any IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `is_checkout()` on your condition then change the fields to billing_address_1 and 2.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readonly_billing_account_fields', 25, 1 );
function readonly_billing_account_fields ( $billing_fields ) {
    // Only my account billing address for logged in users
    if( (is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page()) || is_checkout()){

        $readonly = ['readonly' => 'readonly'];

        $billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}
```